# JavaScript validation using inputs as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, validation

Hi I am trying to validate my inputs using JavaScript, I have the inputs in an array and I am trying to use them to extract information like `.value` and set values such as `.className`. This is not working as I would like it to. What I want the code to do is if I define `input[1] = document.forms["register"]["username"];` then use `input[1].value` it interprets this as if I have written `document.forms["register"]["username"].value`

Here is my original code:

```
function validateForm() {
    var inputs = [];
    inputs[0] = document.forms["register"]["firstname"];
    inputs[1] = document.forms["register"]["lastname"];
    inputs[2] = document.forms["register"]["username"];
    inputs[3] = document.forms["register"]["email"];
    inputs[4] = document.forms["register"]["password"];
    inputs[5] = document.forms["register"]["confirmpassword"];

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].value == null || inputs[i].value == "") {
            alert("Highlighted fields must be filled out");
            inputs[i].className += " invalid";
            return false;

        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is my updated code, I am unsure of whether this is good practice:

```
        function validateForm() {
        var error = false;
        var inputs = [];
            inputs[0] = document.forms["register"]["firstname"];
            inputs[1] = document.forms["register"]["lastname"];
            inputs[2] = document.forms["register"]["username"];
            inputs[3] = document.forms["register"]["email"];
            inputs[4] = document.forms["register"]["password"];
            inputs[5] = document.forms["register"]["confirmpassword"];
            console.log(inputs.length);

        for (i = 0; i < (inputs.length); i++) { 
            if (inputs[i].value == null || inputs[i].value == "") {
                error = true;
                inputs[i].className += " invalid";
                if (inputs[i] == (inputs.length - 1)) {
                    alert("Highlighted fields must be filled out");
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

    if (error == false) {
        return true;
    }

    alert("Highlighted fields must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
```

The class invalid adds a red border to the field.

Thanks.

Comment: _Yes_, It is not clear.. Also add your markup..You are adding array index from `1` and dealing with it from index `0` in `for-loop`

Comment: Any errors in your console? Cause your loop looks like it should throw one.

Comment: I see this error in the console: register.php:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
I have started the array from 0 now.

Comment: and did it solve your problems?

Comment: add html you are using

Comment: I have changed the code and my problem is now solved, but I am unsure of whether it is the best practice. Should I update the code in the question?

Comment: well you can update your code and we'll look at it if you have further questions but well, best practice is hard to comment on for a little function snippet. it depends on your whole environment.

Comment: No. It is not good to fix your question to *working* code. It makes the question confusing and will discourage others from giving you any points. If you notice it's a simple syntax error, perhaps you should delete the question - so you no one downrates it.  Otherwise, yes include any code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed your function a bit to read input elements as in the plnkr link below
https://plnkr.co/edit/zHhM6lmz3XA2u4CYr9h0?p=preview

```
function validate() {
  var inputs = [];
  var elements = document.forms["register"].elements;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.type === "text" || element.type === "email" || element.type === "password") {
        inputs.push(element)
    }
   }

  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    if (inputs[i].value == null || inputs[i].value == "") {
      alert("Highlighted fields must be filled out");
      inputs[i].className += " invalid";
      return false;

    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

I have handled three input types

1. text
2. email
3. password

You can add more later if needed

**Edit**: Possible cause of error can be DOM element not available inside the `form` (please share `HTML` if possible). First loop will read all available DOM element from the form.

Comment: yes, it's not an answer to the question. just some modified code that doesn't help anyone. you didn't even elaborate your changes.

Comment: it is a modified code to read all the inputs from form. Since in the question markup was not shared it was a guess that a possible issue could have been accessing the elements also the plnkr link if you check, correctly explains and it works as desired in question. not sure if it deserves a downvote. it is just an alternate approach to same issue

Comment: `a guess that a possible issue`. That's the point. I just don't like the vote fishing. posting some code which probbbbaaaably helps someeeone but at minimum effort for yourself. The point is to help understand the mistakes the OP made and help him getting better writing his own code, even find a solution on his own. Saw my "Any errors in your console? Cause your loop looks like it should throw one." comment to his question? that was enough to get him to the right direction and was more helpful for him than a wall of code which he could copy / paste.

Comment: i will remove the downvote if you'll at least edit your question why you changed the logic of his code instead of fixing and explaining his code.

Comment: i appreciate your comment but just to be clear from my side when I saw the question it was already edited to `inputs[0]` and there was no marked answer so for me question was still open and with provided input all you can do is `guess`

Answer (score -1):

```
 function validateForm() {
        var inputs = [];
            inputs[0] = document.forms["register"]["firstname"];
            inputs[1] = document.forms["register"]["lastname"];
            inputs[2] = document.forms["register"]["username"];
            inputs[3] = document.forms["register"]["email"];
            inputs[4] = document.forms["register"]["password"];
            inputs[5] = document.forms["register"]["confirmpassword"];

        for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
            if (inputs[i].value == null || inputs[i].value == "") {
                alert("Highlighted fields must be filled out");
                inputs[i].className += " invalid";
                return false;

            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: how is this helpful?

Comment: The index of the array being posted initially was starting with 1 instead of zero. It has been modified at later poin of time which I missed.

Comment: yes i saw that. and maybe you should explain it in your answer next time, what you changed or how your code is helpful to the OP. Would have been enough to write a comment.